# In python, append child to root.children(list), and child.children(list) changed?

Tags: python

code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, children=[]):
        self.key = key
        self.children = children

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.key
```

execute:

```
root = Node("root")
child = Node("child")
root.children.append(child)
print child.children
print root.children[0].children
```

result:

```
[child]
[child]
```

This is really weird, why?

Python's version is 2.7.2.

Comment: Mutable object as default value! `def __init__(self, key, children=None): \\ children=children or []`

Comment: No, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/623518

Comment: @LeoDT: Not a bug. More like surprising feature. If you think about it hard enough, it makes sense why it would work like that.

Comment: The default value is a property of the _function object_. If you change it, you change it on the function object, so you change it for all calls to the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use mutable objects as default value of arguments (unless you exactly know what you're doing). See [this article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/01/16/python-insight-beware-of-mutable-default-values-for-arguments/) for explanation.

Instead use:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, children=None):
        self.key = key
        self.children = children if children is not None or []
```

Comment: alternatively: `self.children = children if children is not None else []` or `self.children = [] if children is None else children`.

Comment: `children or []` is not quite the same as `if children is not None`, because there are many false values which are not `None`. This may matter to you, or it may not, but the usual idiom is the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key,children): # don't use children =[] here, it has some side effects, see the example below
        self.key = key
        self.children =children

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.key

root = Node("root",[])
child = Node("child",[])
root.children.append(child)
print root.children
print root.children[0].key
```

**output:**

```
[child]
child
```

**example:**

```
def example(lis=[]):
    lis.append(1) #lis persists value
    print(lis)
example()
example()
example()
```

output :

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: @Secator no it isn't , but `children or [] ` thing didn't came to my mind while I was writing this.